# YOURLS security settings on Dreamhost?

Tags: php, yourls

I think I have installed YOURLS correctly, but I get the spinning wheel that never ends when I try to shorten a code.

I've tried to follow the instructions on the Troubleshooting page.
https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/wiki/Endless-Spinning-Icon

I typed the Ajax code he suggested, and it properly (I think) returns the main page of my URL. So I believe that means I've got things correctly setup. Although I have looked at my settings many times, I will admit there's a chance I did something wrong that I just haven't found yet.

He suggests the problem could be "overzealous mod_security configuration preventing all urls containing url=http:// from being successfully returned." So I switched off "Extra Web Security" in the Dreamhost Settings. Still no luck. The error logs don't show anything (after the last round of errors during setup).

My questions:
1. Is there some other security setting anyone knows of that I need to fix in Dreamhost?
2. Any suggestions of ways to track down any errors I might have not found in the setup of the database?
Thanks.

Comment: There are 15 settings to be set in config.sys. One at a time, I've changed all of them except the login protection and the 36/62 setting. Every time I change something, usually the code fails and can't run. Then I switch it back, and it runs fine except the spinning ball bit. So as far as I can tell, I have config.sys setup correctly.  He says 99% of the time the problem is user error, which I am not discounting here. But I really think I've got config.sys setup right. So I guess there must be some server configuration that I still haven't got right, and I'm hoping someone has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say I solved my own question, but it's not very satisfying.  I was working on a Windows 10 laptop the last few days, and anytime I tried to create a Short URL, I got the spinning wheel and I couldn't find anything wrong with the settings. Today, I tried it on my work desktop mac and PC running windows 7, and on both of them, the YOURLS interface works perfectly fine. I can create short codes, and they work.  Why does it work on a Mac and Windows 7 but not my Windows 10 laptop? I guess that's the next question.

But for anyone reading this later, if you think you have YOURLS setup properly, and can't figure out why you have the spinning ball, my suggestion is to try accessing the /admin page from a different machine, and see if that makes any difference.

Before it magically fixed itself, I was going to look into the mod_rewrite settings as my next step, but I didn't need to.

Comment: Ugh. So my victory dance was premature. For one brief, shining moment it worked fine on my Windows 7 desktop, and now it doesn't. But the Mac is still perfectly fine.  I thought maybe the problem was being logged into /admin from multiple machines, so I logged out of the others, and only logged into one machine, my W7 desktop, but all I get is the spinning wheel. This, as you can all relate to, is frustrating.